# Olark callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax, chat

I can see with firebug there are not post or get request as you chat online using Olark http://www.olark.com/. Does somebody know how they send data without callbacks. I can see the callbaks clearly in gmail chat using firebug.

Thanks

Comment: Install [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) for Firefox and it'll show you all HTTP traffic. If it's not there, then they're using Web Sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking as an engineer at Olark, we pass data back and forth with long-polling GET requests. They're visible in Inspector or Firebug on the network tab:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uznJV.png

Comment: Just wondering, would it make sense to supercede long-polling AJAX with WebSockets when available in the browser?

Comment: Yeah, long-polling can serve as a fallback to WebSockets behavior, but it takes careful engineering to keep your flows abstract enough that they don't care how the data is coming in. This has a lot of implications for the advantages you can get out of WebSockets, too, because you'll still be finding yourself treating the data coming in as if it's coming from a poll (rather than being pushed through a socket).